# Swift 3 Using a Table view to display Parse objects- How to limit the number of objects displayed

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pull-to-refresh

Swift 3 - Xcode 8
I'm using a Table view to download & display all the objects in the className : "Task".  But how do I limit the number of objects to 25 and only load 25 more when the user gets to the bottom of the table view ?

And how can the user pulldown to refresh to get the latest Task ? I thank you in advance !!!

```
   let query = PFQuery(className: "Task")
    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if let posts = objects{
            for object in posts {
                if let post = object as? PFObject {

                    self.taskType.append(post["type"] as! String)
                    self.taskTitle.append(post["title"] as! String)
                    self.taskDescription.append(post["description"] as! String)
                    self.taskPostal.append(post["postal"] as! String)
                    self.taskRegion.append(post["region"] as! String)
                    self.taskAmount.append(post["amount"] as! String)
                    self.taskAmountType.append(post["amountType"] as! String)

                    self.taskId.append(object.objectId!)



                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: FWIW the technique you're describing (25 items at a time) is called pagination. There are several tutorials using iOS on the web that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Dwifft](https://github.com/jflinter/Dwifft) which is very simple and will update your rows automaticaly with neat animations and without suttering.

Add Dwifft+UIKit.swift and Dwifft.swift files to your project. Configure your UITableViewController similar to as in DwifftExample. You have to pick up your datasource which in your case could be taskTitle array property (apply in didset of it self.diffCalculator?.rows = taskTitle). Use this property to return the count of it in numberOfrowsInSection delegate method as in the example.

Inside your query when iterating through your objects and appending them to the properties' arrays first add them to the local arrays and outside the for loop add to properties with +=.

When it comes to pagination play with **query.limit = 25** and **query.skip** of Parse. Then in tableView delegate method willDisplayCell check if the indexPath.row == taskTitle.count - 1 and then perform another query keeping the track of **.skip** value.

Implement pull to refresh with UIRefreshControl() and remember to clean your properties arrays with .removeAll(keepCapacity: Bool) also clean the .skip value

**You do not have to use .reloadData()** along with Dwifft as it will perform updates of your cells automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit and skip, like below

let query = PFQuery(className: "Task")
query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

query.limit = 50

query.skip = 0 //skip 0 records, then next time you execute this function then setup skip = 50, then will skip 50 records.

query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in